# Got "Not Found" status code for an existing question

Tags: bug, status-norepro

#### What steps will reproduce the problem?

1. click on ["What programming languages do you consider indispensable in your experience?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193503/what-programming-languages-do-you-consider-indispensable-in-your-experience)

#### What is the expected output? What do you see instead?

Expected content of the page. Got "HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found."

"View Page Source" shows that the correct page is returned (only status code is invalid).

#### Software versions

Firefox 3.6.3 Ubuntu 10.04

It might be just a temporary glitch

Comment: @Jeff, it is a temporary glitch indeed, and has happened to me as well, for other questions on the trilogy. A refresh always fixed it right away; I've yet to see the same error when refreshing. A bit hard to troubleshoot, unless the access logs somehow show a 404 for the URL from this question? The 404 is a SOFU error page, not some browser message. (Adding this to my favourites to post URLs if it happens to me again.)

Comment: A View Source in Firefox actually requests the page *again*, so I guess that explains seeing the question when doing View Source. Other browser show the source of the page as it's currently shown.

Comment: By the way, @Jeff: I *think* I've only seen this when clicking an item in my browser's history, and never when following a link from a SOFU homepage or (Google) search results. Hence, *maybe* it's related to some session thing? (Surely, following an old *edit* link from the browser history, like `posts/49262/edit-submit/d1b73e31-d806-4f7d-aa4c-900112b952ff`, gets one an error too, but that's *not* what I'm referring to.) It's not a new issue; I've seen it before and indeed one time today as well if I recall correctly...

Comment: J.F., did you post this question soon after it happened to you? (To give the crew some timeframe, to see if it indeed might have been caused by some update after all -- and hence `status-norepro` might indicate: meanwhile solved.)

Comment: @Arjan: I've posted in ~5 minutes after it happened.

Answer (score 1):

In the lower-right corner, a version number is shown, like `revision: 2010.5.8.6`. If after a browser refresh the first part is today's date, then a new version might just have been deployed.

Comment: I've seen that happen a couple of times; I think it happens when they push an update or something like that.

Comment: Yep, we just deployed a new version - there can be a few 404s depending on how unlucky you are.

Comment: Aha, next time, if I happen to still have another window open, I'll look at the version number in the lower-right corner, or peek into the HTML to get the version numbers (like from `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://sstatic.net/mso/all.css?v=ee971a626dcf">`), and compare those to the values from a refreshed page...

Comment: @Geoff, do you still want us to post here, if it happens again in the coming weeks? Or are you confident it's always due to some maintenance? (And: does it matter if it is a very basic message, or a nice 404 page?)

Comment: Ah, that revision in the lower-right corner is actually a date, like `revision: 2010.5.8.6` :-) (So, I changed my answer.)